# How to take derivative of Ky Fan $k$ norms of a matrix $A$: $\frac{\partial\|A\|_k}{\partial A}$

Tags: derivatives, optimization, convex-analysis, normed-spaces, matrix-calculus

The  [Ky Fan $k$ norms](http://www.njohnston.ca/2009/08/ky-fan-norms-schatten-norms-and-everything-in-between/) of matrix $A$ is define as

$$ \|A\|_k = \sum_{i=1}^k \sigma_i(A)$$

where $ \sigma_i(A)$ is the singular value of $A$ in descent order.

Is it possible to compute the Ky Fan $k$ norms of matrix $A$ since the Ky Fan $k$ norms is [convex](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/318351/about-the-convexity-of-ky-fans-norm):

$$\frac{\partial\|A\|_k}{\partial A}$$

Note: $A$ can be nonnegative.